# Ignore #'¡DIV/0! Values in both axes of a bar chart - Excel

Tags: excel, visualization, data-visualization

I have this bar chart in excel :

[image]

As you see, if there is `#'¡DIV/0!`, the values are `0`. What I really want is that the bar chart just shows the numeric values. In this case. just the first three values would have to be visualized. I tried the formula `IF.ERROR(FORMULA,"")` but the result was the same,

So, How Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic ranges for the chart, or filter the data source to hide the rows with the error. Excel charts will not include data that is hidden with a filter.

To apply dynamic ranges, create two range names with the following formulas:

```
chtLabels   =OFFSET(chtValues,0,-1)
chtValues   =Sheet1!$B$12:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(99^99,Sheet1!$B:$B,1))
```

Adjust the chtValues range name to start in the first cell with a number in column B instead of B12 of the example.

Edit the column chart series values and enter the range name, preceded by the sheet name, like

```
=Sheet1!chtValues
```

Edit the Horizontal axis labels and replace the range with the dynamic named range

```
=Sheet1!chtLabels
```

When you exit the dialog, Excel will replace the sheet name with the file name. The result will be similar to this:

[image]

Note how the series formula shows the range names instead of the cell ranges.

Comment: Would this work using `indirect()` directly in the chart data source? (by the way, excelent answer)

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(value, value_if_error)` where value_if_error should equal 0 or "" or whatever you want

Comment: I get it but that doesn't hide the labels of the error in the Y-Axis of the graph.

Comment: Why not insert a hidden column with an "if" formula populating the label if the value isn't 0 (or error or "") - then use the hidden column to produce the chart and just tell it to ignore gaps (or 0s)