# Plot only non-empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I would like to plot only cells that are non-empty.

Currently my plots look like the `Desired Outcome` plot.

[image]

I would like to display only non-empty data in my bar-plot.

I tried under: Select Data Source > Hidden and Empty Cells > Gaps ,but still all non empty values are displayed.

Further, it is no option for me to change the data source all the time, as the NA() formulas will get filled at a later point in time.

Any suggestions how to do that in excel 2010?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What if you limit your range to what you want displayed on the chart?  It is much simpler than trying to hide data.

Comment: @radiocontrolled In my other cells, there are formulas, which get filled on a later point in time. Changing the range all the time, wouldn`t make the excel automatic!

Comment: Does this help: [Chart that Ignores N/A! Errors and Empty Values](http://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/327-chart-ignore-empty-values)

Comment: And check this out as well: [Ignore #'¡DIV/0! Values in both axes of a bar chart - Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27049436/4792911)